Menu with switch case and while loop
I want to create a menu where you can choose which program you want to use and have an option to return and repick another program but i got some problem. When i return to pick another program i cant pick anything, it just print a menu again and again.
int choose;
    int manage1;

   while(manage1!=9) {
        printf("Choose which program you want to use!\n");
        printf("1.Students in a class\n");
        printf("2.Motorbikes in a shop\n");
        printf("3.Book in a library\n");
        printf("4.Drugs in a store\n");
        printf("5.Equipment in a laboratory\n");
        printf("6.Food in a mini market\n");
        printf("7.Fruit in a fruit shop\n");
        printf("8.Items in sport shop\n");
        printf("9.Out!\n");
        scanf(" %d",&manage1);
        switch (manage1) {
            case 3:
                while (choose != 12) {
                    printf("1.Display\n");
                    printf("2.add new object\n");
                    printf("3.Sort by name\n");
                    printf("4.Sort by quanity\n");
                    printf("5.Sort by year\n");
                    printf("6.Searching for a book name\n");
                    printf("7.Searching for a book code\n");
                    printf("8.Delete by a book name\n");
                    printf("9.Delete by a book code\n");
                    printf("10.Delete all\n");
                    printf("11.Export infomation into a file\n");
                    printf("12.Return!\n");
                    scanf("%d", &choose);
                    switch (choose) {
                        case 1:
                            //Do something

                            break;
                      
                        case 12:
                            printf("Exit!\n");

                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Wrong syntax\n");
                            break;

                    }
                }
               break;
            case 4:
                while (choose != 12) {
                    printf("1.Display\n");
                    printf("2.add new object\n");
                    printf("3.Sort by name\n");
                    printf("4.Sort by quanity\n");
                    printf("5.Sort by year\n");
                    printf("6.Searching for a book name\n");
                    printf("7.Searching for a book code\n");
                    printf("8.Delete by a book name\n");
                    printf("9.Delete by a book code\n");
                    printf("10.Delete all\n");
                    printf("11.Export infomation into a file\n");
                    printf("12.Return!\n");
                    scanf("%d", &choose);
                    switch (choose) {
                        case 1:
                            //Do something

                           break;
                      
                        case 12:
                            printf("Exit!\n");

                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Wrong syntax\n");
                            break;

                    }
                }
                case 9:
                printf("Exit the program!");

                
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong syntax\n");
                break;
}}

Is it problem from the scanf or something. I hope you guy can help me. Thank you

Add choose = 0; to each case, before the whiles.

Also initialize manage1.

Always check that input operations succeeded — always test the return value from scanf() or any of the other functions in that family of functions.

Side note: Assuming that you have a strict menu hierarchy, it would probably be better for every sub-menu to have its own function. See this answer of mine to another question for an example.

Change each while loop to a do … while loop.
The first time while(manage1!=9) is executed, the value of manage1 has not been set, and its value is in an indeterminate state. There is no reason to expect it will not be 9 (or that it will be 9).
By making this a do … while loop, the program will execute the body of the loop, which sets manage1 in a scanf call, and then it tests manage1!=9 later.
Similarly, the first time while (choose != 12) is executed, choose has not been set. But there is an additional problem. Once you enter one of these sub-menu loops and exit it by entering 12, choose has been set to 12 and is never changed. The next time while (choose != 12) is executed, choose will still be 12, and the body of the loop will not be entered, and choose will not change. Your program has no way of getting back into these loops. Again, using do … while will fix this by entering the loop first, where choose will then be set in the body of the loop.

If something is entered that cannot be parsed as an integer ( such as a) the scanf for integer will fail until the invalid input is removed and the menu will repeat over and over.
scanf ( "%*[^\n]"); will scan and discard everything that is not a newline. If the preceding scan for an integer fails, this will remove the invalid input. scanf with the %d specifier will skip leading whitespace.
Consider putting each sub-menu in it's own function.
#include <stdio.h>

void bookmenu ( void) {
    int choose = 0;
    while ( choose != 12) {
        printf ( "1.Display\n");
        printf ( "2.add new object\n");
        printf ( "3.Sort by name\n");
        printf ( "4.Sort by quanity\n");
        printf ( "5.Sort by year\n");
        printf ( "6.Searching for a book name\n");
        printf ( "7.Searching for a book code\n");
        printf ( "8.Delete by a book name\n");
        printf ( "9.Delete by a book code\n");
        printf ( "10.Delete all\n");
        printf ( "11.Export infomation into a file\n");
        printf ( "12.Return!\n");
        choose = 0;
        if ( EOF == scanf ( "%d", &choose)) {
            return;
        }
        scanf ( "%*[^\n]");
        switch ( choose) {
            case 1:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 12:
                printf ( "Exit!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf ( "Wrong syntax\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

void drugmenu ( void) {
    int choose = 0;
    while (choose != 12) {
        printf ( "1.Display\n");
        printf ( "2.add new object\n");
        printf ( "3.Sort by name\n");
        printf ( "4.Sort by quanity\n");
        printf ( "5.Sort by year\n");
        printf ( "6.Searching for a drug name\n");
        printf ( "7.Searching for a drug code\n");
        printf ( "8.Delete by a drug name\n");
        printf ( "9.Delete by a drug code\n");
        printf ( "10.Delete all\n");
        printf ( "11.Export infomation into a file\n");
        printf ( "12.Return!\n");
        choose = 0;
        if ( EOF == scanf ( "%d", &choose)) {
            return;
        }
        scanf ( "%*[^\n]");
        switch ( choose) {
            case 1:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 12:
                printf ( "Exit!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf ( "Wrong syntax\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main ( void) {
    int manage1 = 0;

    while ( manage1 != 9) {
        printf ( "Choose which program you want to use!\n");
        printf ( "1.Students in a class\n");
        printf ( "2.Motorbikes in a shop\n");
        printf ( "3.Book in a library\n");
        printf ( "4.Drugs in a store\n");
        printf ( "5.Equipment in a laboratory\n");
        printf ( "6.Food in a mini market\n");
        printf ( "7.Fruit in a fruit shop\n");
        printf ( "8.Items in sport shop\n");
        printf ( "9.Out!\n");
        manage1 = 0;
        if ( EOF == scanf ( "%d",&manage1)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "EOF\n");
            return 1;
        }
        scanf ( "%*[^\n]");
        switch ( manage1) {
            case 3:
                bookmenu ( );
                break;
            case 4:
                drugmenu ( );
                break;
            case 9:
                printf ( "Exit the program!");
                break;
            default:
                printf ( "Wrong syntax\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}


I agree with the suggestion to put each sub-menu in its own function.  I'd prefer to see error checking on each call to scanf() — except perhaps the ones using %*[^\n]".

One of the other answers has already pointed out the cause of your immediate problem: You are reading the value of an uninitialized variable, which can be fixed by not using a while loop, but instead using a different type of loop.
However, in my opinion, the biggest problem in your code is that you are trying to write everything into the function main, instead of dividing your program into functions for the individual sub-menus. I have therefore rewritten your program to use functions for the individual sub-menus. Note, however, that I am assuming that your menus have a strict hierarchy (i.e. if you go down the menu hierarchy through a certain menu, then you will always go through the same menu again when going back up the hierarchy). If you don't want to have this limitation, then you can look at this answer of mine to another question for an alternative way of implementing menus.
Also, I don't recommend using scanf for user input, because that is not what scanf was designed for. For example, if the user enters 6abc, then scanf will successfully convert the character 6, but will leave abc on the input stream. This will cause all further attempts of using scanf to read a number to fail, until the abc is removed from the input stream.
For this reason, I recommend always reading a whole line of input at once with fgets and then to attempt to convert that input to a number. The function get_int_from_user from this answer of mine to another question accomplishes this. You can use that function in your code as shown below.
I have modified your code to fix all of the mentioned issues:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

void main_menu( void );
void sub_menu_books_in_a_library( void );
void sub_menu_drugs_in_a_store( void );
int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt );

int main( void )
{
    main_menu();
}

void main_menu( void )
{
    for (;;) // infinite loop, equivalent to "while(true)"
    {
        int choice;

        printf(
            "\n"
            "Main Menu:\n"
            "Choose which program you want to use!\n"
            "1.Students in a class\n"
            "2.Motorbikes in a shop\n"
            "3.Book in a library\n"
            "4.Drugs in a store\n"
            "5.Equipment in a laboratory\n"
            "6.Food in a mini market\n"
            "7.Fruit in a fruit shop\n"
            "8.Items in sport shop\n"
            "9.Out!\n"
        );

        choice = get_int_from_user( "Please enter choice: " );

        switch ( choice )
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                printf( "\nNot implemented.\n" );
                break;
            case 3:
                sub_menu_books_in_a_library();
                break;
            case 4:
                sub_menu_drugs_in_a_store();
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
                printf( "\nNot implemented.\n" );
                break;
            case 9:
                printf( "\nExiting the program!" );
                return;
            default:
                printf( "\nInvalid choice!\n" );
        }
    }
}

void sub_menu_books_in_a_library( void )
{
    for (;;) // infinite loop, equivalent to "while(true)"
    {
        int choice;

        printf(
            "\n"
            "Sub-menu: Book in a library\n"
            "1.Display\n"
            "2.add new object\n"
            "3.Sort by name\n"
            "4.Sort by quanity\n"
            "5.Sort by year\n"
            "6.Searching for a book name\n"
            "7.Searching for a book code\n"
            "8.Delete by a book name\n"
            "9.Delete by a book code\n"
            "10.Delete all\n"
            "11.Export infomation into a file\n"
            "12.Return!\n"
        );

        choice = get_int_from_user( "Please enter choice: " );

        switch ( choice )
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                printf( "\nNot implemented.\n" );
                break;                      
            case 12:
                printf( "\nExiting!\n" );
                return;
            default:
                printf( "\nInvalid choice!\n" );
        }
    }
}

void sub_menu_drugs_in_a_store( void )
{
    printf( "\nSub-menu not implemented.\n" );
    return;
}

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6abc" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}

This program has the following behavior:
Main Menu:
Choose which program you want to use!
1.Students in a class
2.Motorbikes in a shop
3.Book in a library
4.Drugs in a store
5.Equipment in a laboratory
6.Food in a mini market
7.Fruit in a fruit shop
8.Items in sport shop
9.Out!
Please enter choice: 3

Sub-menu: Book in a library
1.Display
2.add new object
3.Sort by name
4.Sort by quanity
5.Sort by year
6.Searching for a book name
7.Searching for a book code
8.Delete by a book name
9.Delete by a book code
10.Delete all
11.Export infomation into a file
12.Return!
Please enter choice: 12

Exiting!

Main Menu:
Choose which program you want to use!
1.Students in a class
2.Motorbikes in a shop
3.Book in a library
4.Drugs in a store
5.Equipment in a laboratory
6.Food in a mini market
7.Fruit in a fruit shop
8.Items in sport shop
9.Out!
Please enter choice: 9

Exiting the program!

